# XC 9.2 installation error- configuration contains no tasks

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I am installing Sitecore Commerce 9.2 on my local machine. Whilst doing so I see following warning and the scripts stops -

```
VERBOSE: Registering Task extension 'TestWebFeatureSSL' => 'Test-WebFeatureSSL'
VERBOSE: Registering task parameter map
VERBOSE: WarningAction => Continue
VERBOSE: Verbose => Continue
VERBOSE: InformationAction => Continue
VERBOSE: WhatIf => False
VERBOSE: Debug => SilentlyContinue
VERBOSE: ErrorAction => Stop
WARNING: Configuration contains no tasks
[TIME] 00:00:00
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\sc920_com_install\SIF\Master_SingleServer.190902 (14).log
```

I have checked the paths looks good, also checked Master_SingleServer.json and has Parameters, Variables and Includes. Checked one of the include i.e. ".\Configuration\Commerce\IdentityServer\IdentityServer.Config.json"
and it contains tasks.

Anybody faced this issue or specifically where to look for "Registering task parameter map".

Comment: Please add last couple of entries from the log file mentioned at the end of the script. Also please add content of your ps1 script that you are trying to run. Maybe there is typo there or something.

Comment: You don't want to look for "Registering task parameter map". You want to look at what it tells you; "WARNING: Configuration contains no tasks".

Answer (score 1):

got this working- basically I had multiple verions of SIF on my machine and was using old version 1.2.1. 
Had to switch the version using following-

```
Remove-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework
Import-Module -Name SitecoreInstallFramework -RequiredVersion 2.1.0
```